# Python 3 if statements calling wrong function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
if action == 1:
    forage()
elif action == 2:
    forage()
else:
    display()
```

Without knowing the context of what I'm trying to do, here's my problem: whenever I put in 1 or 2, it calls display() rather than calling forage().

Sorry if this question is too dumb to be Stackoverflow material I suppose, but I seem to get this problem a lot and I want it solved once and for all, and can't seem to find a solution. Hopefully you guys can help me.

Comment: Where is `action` defined? Is that user input?

Comment: Sorry: action = input("What do you want to do? ")

Comment: What happens if you run it through a debugger or put a simple 'print "This is x"' statement inside each block?

Comment: Scott: I made everything say "This is c", and it always says "This is c."

Comment: @sbb0 If you made "everything" say the same thing, how can you distinguish between one or the other?

Comment: And it works fine for me: http://ideone.com/ufo9r

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: a crucial flaw in your test is that you're using Python 2.6.4, not Python 3. With Python 3, http://ideone.com/ap9y8

Answer (score 7):

This is a [difference between Python 2 and Python 3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/).  In Python 2, [the `input` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input) would evaluate the string input as a Python expression and return the integer 1 so your example would work as you expected.  In Python 3, [`input`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input) will return the unevaluated string typed-in, e.g. `'1'`. So, for Python 3, you would need to test against string values, not integer ones.  Or convert the string to an integer using `int()` as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

is it possible that action is the string `'1'` rather than the integer `1`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
action = int(input("What do you want to do? "))
```

Comment: I'll try that, but what does the strip do?

Comment: probably no point.  I just wasn't aware that int() ignores whitespace.  Try it both ways and see if it still works.

Comment: Note here the "try:" put in this answer. It won't have been intended as the beginnings of a `try` block, but it would be advisable to put this in a try block and catch `ValueError`, so you don't crash if a non-number is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging tip: Check your input.

```
print(
    type(action), ascii(action),
    type(1), ascii(1),
    type('1'), ascii('1'),
    '1' == 1
    )
```

Python 2: Use `repr()` instead of `ascii()`